# HTML5 video full screen not populate on android browser on mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5-video

I am trying to open a video in full screen on a mobile browser.
The video is showing just fine, but when I click the "full screen" button on the video, only the sound is playing, without the video nor the controls showing.

Could anyone please help me ?

You can find my HTML code below :

```html
<div class = "container">
<div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-md-12">
    <p class="new-txt-styl-mob">Video Title</p>
    <video class = "ved-sttng-mob" controls id = "control1" src = "video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript code :

```js
var myVideo;
window.onload = function()
{
  myVideo = document.getElementById("control1");
  myVideo.load();
  myVideo.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", setFullScreenMode);
}

function setFullScreenMode()
{
  if(myVideo.requestFullscreen) {
    myVideo.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (myVideo.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    myVideo.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (myVideo.msRequestFullscreen) {
    myVideo.msRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (myVideo.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    myVideo.mozRequestFullScreen();
  }
}
```

And, finally, my CSS code :

```css
.ved-sttng-mob {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

.ved-sttng-mob:-webkit-full-screen {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use allowfullscreen like this

```html
<video class = "ved-sttng-mob" controls id = "control1" src = "video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" allowfullcreen="true">
```

Comment: I tried this but I am facing issue on mobile browser not web browser